# Logic used for checking if value is in a list not working for set

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, logic

I'm writing a program that removes duplicate words from a file regardless of case. A word is defined as any sequence of characters without a space and duplicate, DUPLICATE, Duplicate, and DuPliCate are all duplicates.

I've gotten the program to work by reading in the original text as a list of words (strings) and creating a new list of unique strings by checking whether the current word is in the unique list of words. If it isn't in the unique list, append it to the list; ignoring duplicates of the newline character.

As many of you know, using a list isn't very efficient especially for large text files. So I'm trying to implement this function by using a set to determine whether or not I should append a specific word to the unique list.

This logic works but is inefficient:

```
def remove_duplicates(self):
    """
    :return: void
    Adds each unique word to a new list, checking for all the possible cases.
    """
    print("Removing duplicates...")
    unique = []
    for elem in self.words:
        if elem == '\n':
            unique.append(elem)
        else:
            if elem not in unique \
                    and elem.upper() not in unique \
                    and elem.title() not in unique \
                    and elem.lower() not in unique:
                unique.append(elem)
    self.words = unique
```

So the logical thing to do would be to use a set like so:

```
def remove_duplicates(self):
    """
    :return: void
    Adds each unique word to a new list, checking for all the possible cases.        
    """
    print("Removing duplicates...")
    unique = []
    seen = set()
    for elem in self.words:
        lower = elem.lower()       
        seen.add(lower)
        if elem == '\n':
            unique.append(elem)
        else:
            if lower not in seen:
                unique.append(elem)       
    self.words = unique
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. I end up getting an empty text file. I've printed out the set, and it is not empty. It seems like theres a problem in the nested if statement and am stumped as to what it could be. I've been trying to debug this for hours with no luck. I've even tried writing the if statement exactly how I did in the working inefficient example, but it still give me the same problem. I can't figure out why it's not appending the words to unique.

Sample input:

```
self.words = ["duplicate", "not", "DUPLICATE", "DuPliCate", "hot"]
```

Expected output (need to preserve original order, only keeping the first instance of a duplicate word):

```
 unique = ["duplicate", "not", "hot"]
```

Comment: Are you able to provide sample data and expected output? Also the errors if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the object to `seen` before checking for it, hence it always exists in `seen` on your `if` statement.

```
for elem in self.words:
            lower = elem.lower()       

            if lower not in seen:
                unique.append(elem)
                seen.add(lower) # move your seen statement to exist within the check
self.words = unique

return self.words

Removing duplicates...
['duplicate', 'not', 'hot']
```